# Shortcut Limit jQuery to Specific DOM Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, namespaces

I want restrict jQuery to specific namespace or DOM node. Currently what I do is something lik this on every line

```
$('a' , $node).addClass();
$('li' , $node).removeAttr();
$('div#q' , $node).hide();
```

And so on.. Is there any shortcut/method which I can specify after which the scope of jQuery object will be limited to `$node`.

Comment: The jQuery context selector is implemented, internally, with `find()`, so it'd make more sense to explicitly call the `find()` method yourself: `$node.find('a').hide()` (assuming that the `$` prefix indicates a jQuery-object already, otherwise: `$($node).find('a')`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the $ method directly.

Assign $ to a function returning $node.find() and you're done.

```
    jQuery(function($){
        var $node = $('div');
        var _$ = $;

        $ = function(selector){
            return $node.find(selector);
        };

        $('p:first').fadeOut();

        // Return $ to its previous owner
        $ = _$;
    });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pmYRw/1/

Comment: exactly what i wanted thanks! selecting this as the right answer. Please also paste the code here.

Comment: Editted the answer. Also fixed a problem where $node would go to the global namespace

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your methods, that way you only write the selector once:

```
$('a' , $node).addClass('aclass').removeAttr('rel').hide();
```

or also save the reference in a variable for reusing it:

```
var a = $('a' , $node);
a.addClass('aclass');
a.removeAttr('rel');
a.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of $node (which I assume it is an already instantiated jquery object), you can just write it as a string:

```
$('a', '#main') #≠> all anchor tags under element with main as id

$('a', '#main li') #≠> all anchor tags al li's under element with main as id
```

you can also instantiate the main element first and then search in its subscope:

```
var main = $('#main');
main.find('a');
main.find('li a');
```

this will be much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a' , $node).addClass();
$('a' , $node).removeAttr();
$('a' , $node).hide();
```

rather than tying $('a' , $node) several time you can cache this variable and use it like below. This will improve your performance too.

```
var node  = $('a' , $node);
node.addClass();
node.removeAttr();
node.hide();
```

We can improve this code little bit more by chaining them like below

```
var node  = $('a' , $node);
node.addClass().removeAttr().hide();
```

reusing variable and chaining jquery will have a huge impact on you code.